# CSS font-face not finding font files

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have looked through many answers on this site and other, none are working.  I was using SVG, truetype and EOT.  Removed for simplicity.  Here is what I have tried:

**Testing on Google Chrome 61.0.3163.100**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FONTNAME';
  src:  url('../FONTNAME.woff') format('woff');

  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Also tried:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FONTNAME';
  src:  url('/assets/fonts/FONTNAME.woff') format('woff');

  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Unless I'm wrong Chrome should be able to see WOFF

My folder structure looks like this:

- **assets**

  - styleSheets - *all style sheets in here*
  - fonts       - *all fonts in here*
- index.html

Local works fine.  I tested then deleted to test WEB only.

Also tested to see that .woff file exist at the full address.  That works fine also.

Comment: I use `url` without quotes. Don't really know, does it matter

Comment: Open the developer panel in chrome and check the network calls. Is the browser requesting the font files and is the path correct?

Comment: In what way does local work fine? Do you have the Forsaken font installed on your computer? If so, how can you tell that the @font-face rule doesn't work?

Comment: `src:  url('../fonts/FONTNAME.woff') format('woff');`

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Unless the path name contains quotes itself, I can strongly recommend putting quotes around it at all times. Saves headaches.

Comment: If I'm not wrong it should be `url('../fonts/Forsaken-regular-webfont.woff')`

Comment: @MrLister, thanks, I'll keep it on mind

Comment: @Zoltan Toth - Good question. I had installed, tested, then deleted to test web only - I will update my question

Comment: @Zoltan Toth - Yout got it right.  I needed to add the /fonts/ folder - Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> import fonts from `https://...` url

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto');
p:first-child{font-family: 'Roboto';}
p:last-child{font-family: 'Lato';}
```

```html
<p>https://fonts.google.com<p>
<p>https://fonts.google.com<p>
```